# How does the if block remove repeating characters?

Tags: java

Could some of you please explain to me how exactly does the if part works in this code --

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input a word: ");
    String word = "Programming in Java.";
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){

        // ***** HERE *****
        if (word.indexOf(word.charAt(i)) == i){
            result += word.charAt(i);
        }
        // *****

    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The code is removing all the repeating characters and I cannot put my finger as of how it exactly it does that and I want to fully understand how it works before I continue studying.

Comment: So what do you think `word.indexOf(word.charAt(i))` does?  BTW This is a really inefficient way to remove duplicates, but it works.

Comment: Don't add characters to your posted code that make it non-compilable.

Comment: Also a side issue: please help improve your question by making the title informative. "Need a little explanation" is a terrible title as it does not summarize your actual problem. Better would be "How does the if block remove repeating characters?" or something similar. Please read through the [help] and the [ask] for more on site best practices when asking questions. Note that I've changed the title for you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels will do, its just my first post. I will have a look at them now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I refer you to the [`String.indexOf(int)` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) which says (in part)

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character.

When you say `if(word.indexOf(word.charAt(i)) == i)` that is the same as saying if the current `char` is the first occurrence of the current `char` append it to the `result`. Otherwise don't append it. Thus, it only adds characters if it is their first appearance.